# Is there any noncyclic group such that |G|=|Aut(G)|?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So I was wondering if there were any groups such that $|G|=|\mathrm{Aut}(G)|$. I thought of the cyclic groups of order $p$ and the trivial group but I was wondering if there are any others?

Comment: Note that cyclic groups of order $p$ do NOT have this property.

Comment: In fact no nontrivial cyclic group has the property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $n\in\mathbb{N},n\geqslant 3$ and $n\neq 6$, then $S_n$ is isomorphic to $\textrm{Aut}(S_n)$, which is stronger than what you asked. Indeed, in that case $S_n$ has trivial center and all the automorphims of $S_n$ are inner.

Comment: More generally, complete groups will have this property. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_group